# Angular getting and displaying an object via remote AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display an object I'm getting remotely through AJAX. The error I'm currently getting is:

```
ReferenceError: $stateParams is not defined
```

Here's what I have in **services.js**:

```
.factory('Games', function() {
  var games = $.ajax({
    "url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/dc6n4edu?apikey=[APIKEY]&callback=kimonoCallback",
    "crossDomain":true,
    "dataType":"jsonp"
  });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return games;
    },
    get: function(gameID) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return games[gameId];
    }
  }
});
```

Here's what I have in **controller.js**:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, Games) {
    console.log("test in controller");
  $scope.game = Games.get($stateParams.gameId);
});
```

Here's what I have in **tab-account.html**:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        Hello, {{item}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: what type of call is $ajax? get post ?

Comment: It's a GET that returns an object + array

Comment: $stateParams relates to ui-router. Can you give app.js code where your navigation routes are defined. config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state ......

Comment: $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

Comment: I'm using Ionic Framework's sample tabs app

Comment: You could replace service.js  $.ajax code with JSON to test if the problem lies there e.g. replace with -> var games = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Game1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Game2' },
    { id: 2, name: 'game3' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Game4' }
  ];

Comment: The problem is here. What is the correct AJAX syntax?

Comment: Why not use the angular $http.get instead. The following may be useful http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/backend-data/

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `$stateParams` value in the controller function... but i do think you should look into using `$http` service or a `resource`

```
   .controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Games) {
        console.log("test in controller");
      $scope.game = Games.get($stateParams.gameId);
    });
```